# Problem updating SQL Server 2008 Warhouse Cube

Tags: windows-server-2003, active-directory, sql-server-2008, team-foundation-server

We have a TFS 2008 running on a SQL Server 2008 as base (Windows Server 2003 R2 32 Bit Version).

Short time ago I discovered that the Warhouse data (used by reports and analyzer Service)
isn't updated. becouse we nearly never used the reports it's broken sinse " September 2010"

If I check the Server logs i find the following event Msg:

```
Date (UTC): 10.03.2011 11:28:06
Machine: XXXXXXXXXXXXXX
Application Domain: /LM/W3SVC/1048316701/Root/Warehouse-5-129441362809652769
Assembly: Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Warehouse, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a; v2.0.50727
Process Details:
  Process Name: w3wp
  Process Id: 3116
  Thread Id: 3268
  Account name: ourdomain\generic

Detailed Message: The pending configuration changes were not successfully added to the cube because of the following error: 
System.SystemException: The trust relationship between the primary domain and the trusted domain failed.

   at System.Security.Principal.NTAccount.TranslateToSids(IdentityReferenceCollection sourceAccounts, Boolean& someFailed)
   at System.Security.Principal.NTAccount.Translate(IdentityReferenceCollection sourceAccounts, Type targetType, Boolean& someFailed)
   at System.Security.Principal.NTAccount.Translate(IdentityReferenceCollection sourceAccounts, Type targetType, Boolean forceSuccess)
   at System.Security.Principal.NTAccount.Translate(Type targetType)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Warehouse.OlapCreator.AddAccountToRole(Role role, String accountName, Boolean needToUpdate)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Warehouse.OlapCreator.SetupAnalysisDatabase(Server server, String analysisDBName, String accessUser, String[] dataReaderAccounts)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Warehouse.OlapCreator.CreateOlap(WarehouseConfig whConf, String accessUser, String[] dataReaderAccounts, Boolean dropDB, Boolean processCube)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Warehouse.AdapterScheduler.EnsureCubeIsUpToDate()

For more information, see Help and Support Center at http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/events.asp.
```

Somebody have a clue what to do?
Restarting the services AND the server didn't helped.

Answer (score 0):

currently im migrating our company TFS and while im going through this hellish expreience , i encountered your error in 1 of the first steps.

some googling found me a couple of solutions but none of them worked , the only thing that solved it was the remove the server from the domain and join the domain again.

Hope youll find this useful.

Comment: Hi
I read somwhere else about this solution but I didn't tried it.
We are upgrading/Migrating to Sever 2010, so we don't spend time with this topic any more